# Asignar valores a los atributos (css) de una imagen para un canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen, canvas

Tengo un objeto que tiene un método que crea un elemento `img` dentro de un canvas, el problema es que no he podido darle "*estilo*", lo estuve trabajando con un `div` en vez de un canvas y no tenia problemas. Me carga la imagen bien, solo que sin estilo, he probado con:  `setAttributte('style','...')` y con `oImg.style['atributo'].`

Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias de antemano:

Código:

```
 <body style="background-color: black;">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"
style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
</canvas>

 <script>

 let objeto = new Personaje("id23","30%",0);
 objeto.nacimiento();

</script>

</body>
```

Y aquí está el método de mi clase:

```
nacimiento(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var oImg = document.createElement('img');
    oImg.src = "transparente.png";        

    oImg.style.width="22px";
    oImg.style.height="22px";
    oImg.style.background="url('sprite.png') -3px -3px";
    oImg.style.position="absolute";

        oImg.onload = function(){
     ctx.drawImage(oImg, 0, 0);
        }


}
```

Comment: podrias usar de esta manera: $("#myCanvas").css({"border-color": "#C1E0FF", 
                 "border-width":"1px", 
                 "border-style":"solid","height":"500px","width":"500px"});
       });

Comment: Funciona para el canvas pero lo que quiero modificar es la imagen, por otro lado lo acabo de probar con Jquery para la imagen y tampoco funciona :/

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "transparente.png";
img.onload = function(){
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width = 22, img.height=22);
ctx.stroke();

}
```

Comment: Funciona bien para width y height, pero no resolvería para background y position :/

Comment: El error sólo los tienes en background?

Comment: En cualquier otro atributo que no sea width o height, tampoco funciona trabajando el css de manera independiente :/

Comment: ES porque el darwImage() no tiene otro atributo, solo (top,left,width,height) creo creo q es por esa razón no te deja asignarle otros atributos. Aunque yo veo que tú creas la imagen con Javascript primero.

Comment: Así es, primero la creo y le quiero dar estilo y después la llamo pero no me está respetando mis estilos :/ , la solución temporal que encontré fue no crear la imagen con createElement si no hacerlo directamente en el Html fuera del canvas con todos sus estilos para después llamarla en el método nada más:

    <img id="test" src="transparente.png" alt="The Scream" style="width: 22px; height: 22px; background: url('sprite.png') -3px -3px; position: absolute;">

 var x= getElementById("test");  
 oImg.onload = function(){
 ctx.drawImage(x, 0, 0);
            }